# JAR archive : Timestamp of archived files is GMT .. Any way to change to local?

Tags: java

I have a zip file which was archived using Java (JAR). when I open the zip in winzip or Windows explorer, the timestamp of files are in GMT which causes confusion sometimes. Is there a way to control the Timestamp of files inside zip done by JAR ?

JAR cvfM is the parameter used in the command.

Comment: Ganesh but do you want change the the code or the file timestamp on the jar?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp is the number of milli seconds or seconds passed since january 1st 1970 at GMT+0
this doesnt have any format, this is the rule. if you want to change the locale, create a date or calendar in java with the needed locale, but TimeStamp is by definition gmt+0.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that ? I'm not well versed in Java programming

Answer (score -2):

Set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome
```

or

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome
```

it will put the files into the jar file with the given timezone

### Available Time Zones

Here is a short list of the available time zone ids in the TimeZone returned by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

...

```
America/Toronto
Brazil/Acre
Canada/Eastern
Cuba
EST
EST5EDT
Etc/GMT+5
IET
Jamaica
SystemV/EST5
SystemV/EST5EDT
US/East-Indiana
US/Eastern
US/Indiana-Starke
US/Michigan
```

....

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for your reply .. The archive happens in the Perl script .. Should I include the above command in Perl ?

Comment: Do you use this function http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html ? If yes you need to set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS var http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html

Comment: Yes .. "JAR cvfM jarname archivepath" is the function used .. So .. Before this command is called .. I need to set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable .. Right ? Can you let me know for EST ?

Comment: yes it works for me. If you run jar you can find the line "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris". EST?